# How do I start a table at a certain point on the first page of my document and have it continue to the next if necessary? XSL-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a table I want to start at some point on this first page I'm making and I understand that if I put a block container with position absolute with properties top and left I will get the inside content to start from that point I need. But the content won't go to the next page and it will be cut off at the end of this current one.

I also know that if I put a block:container position as relative it will go on to the next page like I need it too. But it's starting point cannot be defined like it can with position: absolute. So I am stuck! Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple alternatives:

- Use `space-before` on the `fo:table` so that it's pushed down the page the required distance.
- Make an `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page that has an `fo:region-body` (with the applicable `region-name`) that has a top margin that will put the top of the `fo:region-body` at the required distance.  If your FO processor supports XSL 1.1, you can have multiple `fo:region-body` in an `fo:simple-page-master`, so if there's other stuff at fixed positions before the table on the first page, you have the option of putting them in separate flows.

Comment: Tony is correct. If you are saying that your content on "some page" (be it the first, 8th, 100th or whatever) to start at a certain position, then his second bullet is the correct answer and what you wish. That page *because you already know it is different and not randomly selected* should have a page master defined for it in which the content you want to put down matches you requirements.